# Is IMA SDK(v3) have support for AppleTv?

Tags: tvos

I have implemented Google's IMA SDK for my mobile app to display pre-roll ads on video play. I also want to implement it for my AppleTv app where it will display pre-roll, mid-roll and post-roll ad.

As we must add IMA framework(Required) and Webkit framework(optional) to the project, But Webkit framework is missing from framework list when I try to add it.

Is IMA SDK(v3) have support for AppleTv? If yes, please share any link or document describing how to display  pre-roll, mid-roll and post-roll ad in appleTV using IMA SDK. If no, Any idea if google is planning to add support near by?

Please guide.

Comment: As you say, WebKit is not supported on Apple TV. You'll need to do without it.

Comment: I figured it out. IMA SDK doesn't have support for appleTv. But I am worried that what are other ways/third party library to implement pre-roll ads in appleTv.

Comment: Is there any solutions on this. I used the latest IMA SDK 3.10.1 from https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/v3/history. But once ad was loaded my airplay signal was lost and it doesn't playback my video. Any help will be appreciated.